# Performance: rank() vs sub-query. Sub query have lower cost?

Tags: performance, oracle, subquery, rank

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220944/oracle-getting-maximum-value-of-a-group) I decided to test the `rank()` function, trying to see if sub query's are less efficient than rank. So I created a table:

```
create table teste_rank ( codigo number(7), data_mov date, valor number(14,2) );
alter table teste_rank add constraint tst_rnk_pk primary key ( codigo, data_mov );
```

and inserted some records...

```
declare
  vdata date;
begin
  dbms_random.initialize(120401);
  vdata := to_date('04011997','DDMMYYYY');
  for reg in 1 .. 465 loop
    vdata := to_date('04011997','DDMMYYYY');
    while vdata <= trunc(sysdate) loop
      insert into teste_rank 
          (codigo, data_mov, valor) 
        values 
          (reg, vdata, dbms_random.value(1,150000));
      vdata := vdata + 2;
    end loop;
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

And then tested two querys:

```
select * 
  from teste_rank r
 where r.data_mov = ( select max(data_mov) 
                        from teste_rank 
                       where data_mov <= trunc(sysdate) 
                         and codigo = 1 )
   and r.codigo = 1;
```

[image: Explain Plan for sub query]

---

```
select *
  from ( select rank() over ( partition by codigo order by data_mov desc ) rn, t.*
           from teste_rank t
          where codigo = 1
            and data_mov <= trunc(sysdate) ) r
 where r.rn = 1;
```

[image: Explain plan rank()]

As you can see, the cost of sub query is lower than rank(). Is this right? Am I missing something there?

PS: Tested also with a full query in the table and still sub query with the low cost.

**EDIT**

I generated a tkprof of the two query's (traced one, shutdown the database, startup and traced the second).

For subquery

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.02          3          5          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          3          0           0
Fetch        2      0.00       0.00          1          4          0           1
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        4      0.00       0.02          4         12          0           1
```

For `rank()`

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.02          3          3          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        2      0.00       0.00          9         19          0           1
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        4      0.01       0.03         12         22          0           1
```

**Can I conclude that sub query not will always less efficient than rank? When is indicated rank instead of sub query?**

Comment: did you analysed the table and the index?

Comment: (not sure if this works or is against some rule but..)
@Justin Cave, as this quest is related to your answer in other post, can you please see and give your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your question is.  Yes, according to these two execution plans, in this case, the subquery method has a lower expected cost.  Doesn't seem too surprising, since it can use the index to very quickly locate the exact row you're interested in.  Specifically in this case, the subquery only has to do a very quick scan of the PK index.  The situation might be different if the subquery involved columns that weren't part of the index.

The query using `rank()` has to get all the matching rows and rank them.  I don't believe that the optimizer has any short-circuit logic to recognize that this is a top-n query and therefore avoid a full sort, even though all you really care about is the top-ranked row.

You might also try this form, which the optimizer should recognize as a top-n query.  I would expect in your case that it would require only a single range scan on the index followed by a table access.

```
select * 
  from (select *
          from teste_rank r
          where data_mov <= trunc(sysdate) 
            and codigo = 1
        order by data_mov desc)
  where rownum=1;
```

Comment: In the question that I mentioned, one of the answers says that `sub query` is less efficient than `rank()`. I'm trying to confirm that.

Comment: @SérgioMichels: I would say that your test proves that the rank() method is not always more efficient than the subquery method.  Both are reasonable techniques to use to get the desired result, and which one is more efficient will depend on multiple factors such as which columns are involved, how they are indexed, the data size and distribution.  In your case, the subquery is very efficient because it is able to use exactly the columns covered by the index, and take advantage of the ordering of the index entries to avoid an additional sort.  In other cases, this won't be true.

Answer (score 2):

Cost is the cost based optimizer's estimate of what it will take to execute a query.

It's possible for the CBO to get it wrong, especially if statistics are out of date.

So, what to do?  Try executing each query with 'set autotrace on'.  How many buffer gets and physical reads does each query do?  In other words, how much *actual* work does each query do?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course, when looking at the physical reads, caching may come into play.

Comment: @DaveCosta how can I avoid the cache of the query?

Comment: @Mark J. Bobak  thanks for your answer, I updated my question with the result of a tkprof and tried to better explain the question. Can you please see if there's something new to add to the answer? Thanks again :)