# prepare the monthly sales report for the customer who has the maximum sales, for the below table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

[image]

prepare the monthly  sales report for the customer who has the maximum sales, for the below table

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220944/oracle-getting-maximum-value-of-a-group

Comment: Please define "monthly sales report" - that is not a standard term, so you must explain it. Beyond that, it is OK to post your homework and ask for help - but you MUST show your work: what you tried, what didn't work, how the output was different from what you expected, etc. This is not a "do my homework for me" site (although sometimes it feels like it is).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - According to site rules, you must show your work when you ask volunteers to help you with your homework.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can retrieve in 'one' query:

- the id of the customer who has the maximum sales
- the sales summary of this customer

First the query that brings the customer_id and the corresponding summary of sales is like:

```
select customer_id, sum(sales) as sumsales from mytable group by customer_id;
```

To this query, a rank has to be added to the descending order of Sales summaries. This will allow to select a single record according to its rank later. So, a wrap is necessary:

```
select customer_id, sumsales, rank() over (order by sumsales desc) as rnk from
    (select customer_id, sum(sales) as sumsales from mytable group by customer_id);
```

Now that the ranked entries are available, the first ranked record has to be selected:

```
select customer_id, sumsales from
    (select customer_id, sumsales, rank() over (order by sumsales desc) as rnk from
        (select customer_id, sum(sales) as sumsales from mytable group by customer_id)
    )
where rnk=1;
```

However, this may not be the most effective way to achieve this.

EDIT:

In order to avoid a wrapping layer, just to add the rank, it is possible to add the rank foeld to the first internal query:

```
select customer_id, sum(sales) as sumsales, rank() over (order by sum(sales) desc) as rnk
from mytable group by customer_id;
```

And then, a single wrapping query is needed to select the first ranked record as:

```
select customer_id, sumsales from (
    select customer_id, sum(sales) as sumsales, rank() over (order by sum(sales) desc) as rnk
    from mytable group by customer_id
)
where rnk=1;
```

Reference to other similar relevant answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220944/oracle-getting-maximum-value-of-a-group).