# Select row with max value saving distinct column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have values

```
 - id|type|Status|Comment
 - 1 | P  |  1   | AAA
 - 2 | P  |  2   | BBB
 - 3 | P  |  3   | CCC
 - 4 | S  |  1   | DDD
 - 5 | S  |  2   | EEE
```

I wan to get values for each type with max status and with comment from the row with max status:

```
 - id|type|Status|Comment
 - 3 | P  |  3   | CCC
 - 5 | S  |  2   | EEE
```

All the existing questions on SO do not care about the right correspondence of Max type and value.

Comment: I've tried like 20 similar posts on stackoverflow. And none of the answers worked right. And apparently I can't write something of my own

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: getting maximum value of a group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220944/oracle-getting-maximum-value-of-a-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you one row per type, which have max status

```
select * from (
    select  your_table.*, row_number() over(partition by type order by Status desc) as rn from your_table
) tt
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected**: The below will use a subquery to figure out each type and what the max status is, then it joins that onto the original table and uses the where clause to only select those rows where the status equals the max status. Of note, if you have multiple records with the same max status, you will get both of them to come up.

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT type, MAX(STATUS) AS max_status FROM table_name GROUP BY type)
SELECT t2.id, t2.type, t2.status, t2.comment
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t2.type= T1.type
WHERE t2.status = T1.max_status
```

Comment: the subquery here will return all the rows since id is unique and can't be grouped. Why is that used?

Comment: That was my mistake. I modified my answer.